# Laravel Query Builder - Custom Response

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.1, laravel-query-builder

I have a Laravel query like this-

```
public  function rearrangePhoto(Request $request)
{
    $ordering = $request->input('ordering');
    return UserSlidePhoto::where('user_id', Auth::id())
                  ->select(
                            'thumbnail_name',
                            'original_image_name',
                            'id'
                          )
                  ->orderBy('created_at', $ordering)
                  ->get();
}
```

And Model like this-

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class UserSlidePhoto extends Model
{
    protected $table="users_slides_photos";

    protected $fillable=['user_id','social_image_id','provider_key','provider_id','thumbnail_name'];
    public function users()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User')->withTimestamps();
    }
}
```

And I am getting response like this-

```
[{
  "thumbnail_name": "2-hR1vt2ZOOesbpGv00MRbGDYyGAMEqU.jpg",
  "original_image_name": "qweqqwe.jpg",
  "id": 49
},
{
  "thumbnail_name": "2-xqiUrT2lJkEBQ0aA3MmZARmWlAq0BT.jpg",
  "original_image_name": "tyutjh.jpg",
  "id": 50
},
{
  "thumbnail_name": "2-s0zzdC275XqvrT2llBQ4h9sugadCHk.jpg",
  "original_image_name": "asdas.jpg",
  "id": 101
}]
```

I like to get response like this-

```
[{
  "thumbnail_name": "base_url/2-hR1vt2ZOOesbpGv00MRbGDYyGAMEqU.jpg",
  "original_image_name": "qweqqwe.jpg",
  "id": 49
},
{
  "thumbnail_name": "base_url/2-xqiUrT2lJkEBQ0aA3MmZARmWlAq0BT.jpg",
  "original_image_name": "tyutjh.jpg",
  "id": 50
},
{
  "thumbnail_name": "base_url/2-s0zzdC275XqvrT2llBQ4h9sugadCHk.jpg",
  "original_image_name": "asdas.jpg",
  "id": 101
}]
```

So what I have done is this-

```
public  function rearrangePhoto(Request $request)
{
    $ordering = $request->input('ordering');
    $base_url = "base_url/";
    return UserSlidePhoto::where('user_id', Auth::id())
                  ->select(
                            $base_url . DB::raw('thumbnail_name'),
                            'original_image_name',
                            'id'
                          )
                  ->orderBy('created_at', $ordering)
                  ->get();
}
```

And I am getting this error-

[image]

Can anyone please help?

Thanks in advance for helping....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're looking for is Laravel accessor.

```
class UserSlidePhoto extends Model
{
    $base_url = "base_url/";
    protected $table="users_slides_photos";

    protected $fillable=['user_id','social_image_id','provider_key','provider_id','thumbnail_name'];
    public function users()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User')->withTimestamps();
    }

    public getThumbnailNameAttribute($value){
        return $base_url. $value;
    }
}
```

Comment: if you use accessor, when you select thumbnail_name then the basurl is automatically prepended to the value. So you dont have to change any code when retrieving the data.

Answer (score 1):

Try to change your select to this:

```
select(
    DB::raw('concat("'.$base_url.'/", thumbnail_name)'),
    'original_image_name',
    'id'
)
```

But I think better would use `getAttribute`. It can solve your problem even you use JS, because behind the scene Laravel calls `mutator` and in  a response you got what you need.
So you don't need to do any overhead, just write a `mutator`. Hope my answer also can help you.

Answer (score 0):

for that you need to use mutator,for more https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-mutators#accessors-and-mutators.Use this method in your UserSlidePhoto model

```
public function getThumbnailNameAttribute($value)
{
    return $base_url .$value;
}
```

Comment: Not a good option, I like to access it with JS, so I need to get everything done in one place, no function, only in SQL (maybe with CONCAT of MySQL)

Comment: if you use this mutator in your model,and then when you make query your data will change as your expected format.Did you tried it?
At least try a single